Colossians 1:16 New World Translation renders τα πάντα as “all other things” but why is this is not shown in their Kingdom Interlinear?
In Colossians 1:16, the NWT renders τα πάντα as “all other.”
According to Jehovah's Witnesses, Jesus is part of the things created. Is this a correct usage of τα πάντα?
Inconsistently, the same NWT renders Ephesians 1:10 τα πάντα with “all,” This creates the logical dilemma that all things are gathered in Jesus, who is himself part of these things.
The Kingdom Interlinear of the NWT translates τα πάντα in Colossians 1:16 with “all things,” so inconsistency also here.

Although the wall of comments here has been cleaned up, I want to remark that there has been an impeccable quality of cordial and merciful disagreement on this question, full of restraint and understanding across tough doctrinal lines. It's great to see the community engaging so positively even on divisive topics. Thanks for setting a great example.

Colossians 1:16 in the ESV says:


For by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him.


τα πάντα in Greek generally translates to “everything” or "all things".

The phrase τα πάντα (Ta pánta) translates to “everything” in English.
It is used to refer to all things collectively and is often employed
in statements or questions that involve totality. [1]

The New World Translation (NWT) of Jehovah’s Witnesses renders τα πάντα in Colossians 1:16 as “all other things”:

because by means of him all other things were created in the heavens
and on the earth, the things visible and the things invisible,
whether they are thrones or lordships or governments or authorities.
All other things have been created through him and for him. [2]

They render it this way to align with their doctrine that Jesus is part of the created order. This is not widely accepted among scholars. It is matter of fact that τα πάντα does not include the word “other,” and adding it is an interpretative choice used to fit a doctrine rather than a direct translation.
In Ephesians 1:10, the NWT translates τα πάντα as “all things”

for an administration at the full limit of the appointed times, to
gather all things together in the Christ, the things in the heavens
and the things on the earth. Yes, in him [3]

This is certainly an inconsistency in translation. It indeed creates a logical dilemma, as you pointed out. If τα πάντα means “all things” in Ephesians 1:10, it should logically mean the same in Colossians 1:16.
The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures by Jehovah’s Witnesses also translates τα πάντα in Colossians 1:16 as “all things”, which shows very clearly the inconsistency.

To conclude, the translation of τα πάντα as “all other things” in Colossians 1:16 by the NWT is not a proper translation and is influenced by doctrinal interpretation. The more consistent and widely accepted translation is “all things”.

+1 Exactly! It represents a typical result of doctrinal poisoning as a result of moving from pietism to exclusivism to "denominational distinctives" by means of what I call biazogesis. Even in the Apostle Paul's day, we read that people twisted, perverted, and distorted the scriptures (Galatians 1:7, 2 Peter 3:16, 2 Corinthians 4:2) and even the Apostle John wrote "I have written something to the church, but Diotrephes, who likes to put himself first, does not acknowledge our authority." - 3 John 1:9 ESV. So this is what authentic believers should expect to see throughout history!

It got even worse with the NWT of Jehovah’s Witnesses revised version of 2013. They simply have no respect of the greek original text. Explanation: for JWs Christendom is rotten (except them as Jehovahs chosen people). Therefore they invented the urban myth that from the second century on trinitarians falsified the greek originals. JWs say: God Almighty was able to protect his word and his name during 2000 years but after the first century somehow the Holy Ghost weakened and lost his power. Therefore we have to correct the Greek text. What a blasphemy.

yes "generally" but there are declensions of the word.

No, τα πάντα can never be translated as “all other”. The NWT translation of “all other” is a result of translator bias. To translate it as “all other [things]”, the Greek would have stated either πάντα τὰ λοιπά1 or τὰ ἀλλα πάντα.
For example, Plato wrote,2

“Now God,whether because he so willed or because some compulsion was laid upon him not to make more than one couch in nature, so wrought and created one only, the couch which really and in itself is. But two or more such were never created by God and never will come into being.” “How so?” he said. “Because,” said I, “if he should make only two, there would again appear one of which they both would possess the form or idea, and that would be the couch that really is in and of itself, and not the other two.” “Right,” he said. “God, then, I take it, knowing this and wishing to be the real author of the couch that has real being and not of some particular couch, nor yet a particular cabinet-maker, produced it in nature unique.” “So it seems.” “Shall we, then, call him its true and natural begetter, or something of the kind?” “That would certainly be right,” he said, “since it is by and in nature that he has made this and all other things [τἆλλα πάντα].”

τἆλλα πάντα is the Attic Greek equivalent of the Koine Greek τὰ ἀλλα πάντα, both meaning “all other things”.




Footnotes




1  cf. 2 Cor. 13:2: τοῖς λοιποῖς πᾶσιν (KJV: “to all other”); Philemon 1:13: τοῖς λοιποῖς πάσιν (KJV: “in all other”)2 Plato, Republic, § 597d






References




Plato (Πλάτων). Platonis Opera. Ed. Burnet, John. Vol. 4. Oxonii: E Typographeo Clarendoniano, 1903.Plato. Plato in Twelve Volumes. Trans. Shorey, Paul. Vol. 5–6. Cambridge: Harvard UP, 1969.




Never? ! Cor 1:27  EBR "For—He put all things in subjection under his feet. But whensoever it shall be said—All things are in subjection!—It is evident that it means,—Except him who did put into subjection unto him the All things—"   Seems "evident"

The word πάντα (panta) used in Colossians 1:16 and 264 other occurrences in the New Testament are correctly translated as "all" or "all things." For example, Matthew 6:33 reads:

33 But seek first the kingdom of God and his righteousness, and
all (πάντα) these things will be added to you. - Matthew 6:33 ESV

You can find a list of all verses using πάντα here:
https://biblehub.com/greek/panta_3956.htm
The English prefix "pan" (which came from Greek) are present in words like pandemic. Here's a reference to the prefix, pan- :https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pan-
The "τα" is simply an article (i.e. "the") and has absolutely NO connection to the word "other" as added by the NWT.
One can even enter πάντα in Google Translate and in modern Greek. It means . . . "everything." Try it out for yourself here:
https://translate.google.com/?sl=el&tl=en&text=%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1%20&op=translate
Hope this helps.

The New World Translation is wrong, for τα πάντα is "all things", just like in John 1:3. Now, how can He, whom Paul says that "in" and "through" him "all things" is created be a part of this "all things"? Does not the subject, Christ, here, in this Pauline sentence indicate the cause and condition for the τα πάντα (all things) to exist? And how can a condition for all existents to exist can be one of the existents?
Ok, let us play with Jehovah Witnesses and drive our imaginative capacities to the utmost limits for twisting the plain text of the Apostle and hypothesize in line with their article of faith that although Christ is the condition and cause of existence of all creatures, still Himself, the condition is a creature, albeit of a noblest sort. Now, my dear follower (I would say rather a victim) of Charles Taze Russel, just answer my 2 questions:
1. if Christ is simultaneously a creature and a condition of existence of all creatures, will not it follow that He is condition of His own existence? Is it logical? Just think, ha?
2. If Christ is the condition of existence of all things (which He is a part of, as you claim), now, please answer, is He a necessary condition, or can Father create all things without creating Him, Christ? If Christ is not necessary for the Father to create all creatures, then Father, in principle, essentially, could create the universe without Christ, without His Logos, but He simply chose to first create His Logos/Christ and then through Him also the universe, of which His Logos is a part; thus, the Father made a creature, Logos, a condition for other creatures to exist, but this condition is not necessary for Him, for He as God could create even without first creating His Logos. Is that what you think? If so, how can I congratulate you with this mythological imaginations, ha?
But if you will come to senses and affirm, and admit, and confess that Logos is necessary for the Father to create the universe, to the effect that the Father is ontologically unable to create anything without His Logos, then it is impossible for Logos not to be outside of the ranks of the created things and if so, it is impossible for Logos not to be God.

Answer
The New World Translation (NWT) rendering of “τα πάντα” as “all (other) things” in Colossians 1:16 is incorrect and the resultant theology is in clear error.
Explanation
Absolutely there is not even a shred of evidence in the entire Scripture that first God the Father created Jesus Christ and then all the other things were created by Jesus.
Wise men say that instead of one’s theology determining the grammar of the Scripture; it should be the other way around. The grammar should determine one’s theology; otherwise errors could distort the theology.
Devil’s Advocate
One of the principles of natural justice is Audi alteram partem. This stipulates that no one should be judged without a proper hearing. So let us hear what JW.org has to say on this.
They say:
JW.org: _ “All other things: A literal rendering of the Greek text would be “all things.” (Compare Kingdom Interlinear.)”_
One has to gladly acknowledge that they have at least agreed that grammatically the Greek ‘ta panta’ means “all things” and not “all (other) things”. For evidence they refer to their own Kingdom Interlinear!
JW.org: ” However, such a rendering could give the impression that Jesus was not created but was the Creator himself.”
Now here is their ‘a priory’ theology coloring their translation leading to a gross error.
JW.org: ”And that idea would not agree with the rest of the Bible, including the preceding verse, which calls Jesus “the firstborn of all creation.” (Col 1:15; compare Re 3:14, where Jesus is called “the beginning of the creation by God.”)”
Though they say “the rest of the Bible” they give only two references to prove their stand: Jesus is A) “the firstborn of all creation” and B) “the beginning of the creation by God”.
According to the rule of the Scripture, no person – whoever he is – is allowed to interpret the Scripture on his own (2 Pet 1:20). The person should depend on other Scripture to explain the particular Scripture.
So, let us see:
A)  “the firstborn of all creation”:-
The notion that “firstborn” means “first created” is an unwarranted “private” interpretation and is anti-Scriptural.
5 strong points refute the above notion:

Hebrews 12:23 calls the New Testament saints as “the firstborn ones”. But we know for sure that the saints in the NT are NOT the first ever created human beings!

Adam and Eve were the first created human beings!
So, we see that in Scripture firstborn does not mean “first created”. It simply means they are the “first resurrected” from the dead humanity.
So, if “firstborn” does not mean first created here, it cannot mean first created there also, that is, in Colossians 1:15. It is so plain a truth.

Hebrews 1:6 again says: “And again, when He brought the First-born into the world, He said, "And let all the angels of God worship Him."

If Jesus is the first created being before anything, then there shouldn’t be any angels around at that time; only God the Father should be around. But here we see angels already around to worship Jesus when he was created and brought into the world.

Romans 8:29 says: “For those whom he foreknew he also predestined to be conformed to the image of his Son, in order that the Son might be the firstborn among many brothers”.

What? So, Jesus is not already the firstborn! He “might become” the firstborn.
This shows clearly that Jesus’s status of being the firstborn is dependent on other “many brothers”. If there are no other brothers, then Jesus cannot “be the firstborn”! So, again, firstborn doesn’t mean first created.

In fact, the “God-breathed” Scripture itself defines firstborn clearly as the first-resurrected from the dead brothers:


“for Him to be the First-born among many brothers” (Rom 8:29).


“And He is the Head of the body, the church, who is the Beginning, the
First-born from the dead, that He may be pre-eminent in all
things” (Col 1:18).


“even from Jesus Christ the faithful Witness, the First-born from
the dead” (Rev 1:5).


The “all creation” in Colossians 1:15, in Greek, is “pas Ktisis”. This is always related to “human beings”. It has nothing to do with Genesis creation or pre-Genesis creation of anything!


“And He said to them, Going into all the world, preach the gospel to
all the creation [pas ktisis]” (Mark 16:15).

This is Jesus’ final command to His disciples. Yet we know that the apostles never preached the Gospel to mountains, oceans, dogs or animals!
They preached the Gospel only to human beings (all creation/ every creature/ pas ktisis).

“However, you must remain firmly established and steadfast in the
faith, without being moved from the hope of the gospel that you heard,
which has been proclaimed to every creature (pas ktisis) under
heaven and of which I, Paul, have become a servant” (Col 1:23).

The Colossians heard the gospel being preached to “every creature/ all creation/ pas ktisis” of which Paul became a servant.
Yet we know that neither the Twelve apostles nor Paul ever preached the gospel to any inanimate creation or animals. It was preached only to human beings.
Thus, we see that according to the Scripture, “firstborn” does not mean the first created but the “first-resurrected” from the dead human beings. This is the truth.
B)  the beginning of creation by God:-
Again, the term “beginning” (Greek Arche) is not for private interpretation. We need to see how Scripture interprets the term.
The Greek is “arche”. Does it mean the “first created”?
IF it does, then God the Father is also the “first created” because He says, “I am the Alpha and the Omega, the BEGINNING (the same Arche) and the Ending, says the Lord, the One who is, and who was, and who is coming, the Almighty” (Rev 1:8).
Again, “I am the Alpha and the Omega, the BEGINNING (the same Arche) and the Ending” (Rev 21:6).
So, if Jesus, as the Arche, is the first created being, then definitely God the Father also, as the Arche, is the first created being!
Arche with the same context cannot mean one thing in one place and another thing in another place!
Let us continue:
JW.org: ”Also, the Greek word for “all” can in some contexts have the meaning “all other,” as for example at Lu 13:2 (“all other”); Lu 21:29 (“all the other”); Php 2:21 (“all the others”).”
Finally they seem to be making some points here. But, are these valid points? The answer is “no”! Let us study:

Luke 13:2:  “And answering, Jesus said to them, Do you think that
these Galileans were sinners beyond all the Galileans (para pantas
tous Galilaious), because they suffered such things?” (LITV).

Here, the meaning does not change even when “all the (other) Galilians” is not used!
(Besides, “these Galilians” and “all the other Galilians” all belong to the same class/group/category).

Luke 21:29: “And He spoke a parable to them: You see the fig tree and
all the trees” (LITV).

Here, the meaning does not change even when “all the (other) trees” is not used!
(Besides, “the fig tree” and “all the other trees” all belong to the same class/group/category).

Phlp 2:21: “For all (pantes) seek their own things, not the things of
Christ Jesus”.

Here, the meaning does not change even when “all (others)” is not used!
(Besides, “Timothy” and “all other ministers” all belong to the same class/group/category).
But the same is not the case for Colossians 1:16:

“For all things (ta panta) were created in Him.”

First of all, as NWT agreed already, the Greek does not provide for “all the (other) things”.
Secondly, here, unlike the above cited verses where both the things belonged to the same class/group/category, Jesus Christ is contrasted with “all things”. They are standing on opposite sides.
The Scripture does NOT say, “Jesus and all the other things were created by God”. This is not the sense of the verse!
“All things (on the created side) were created in Him (on the Creator side)!
No further comments!
JW.org: ” This agrees with Paul’s inspired teaching found at 1Co 15:27: “God ‘subjected all things under his [Christ’s] feet.’ But when he says that ‘all things have been subjected,’ it is evident that this does not include the One who subjected all things to him.””
This does not at all prove that Jesus was created!
It simply says that the Father is always greater than the Son as acknowledged by Jesus Christ. So, a father is never subjected under a son's feet, even among human beings let alone the God family!
JW.org: _”So both the Bible’s teachings as a whole and the PROBABLE (emphasis mine) meaning of the Greek word used here support the rendering “all other things.””_
Probable? So they are not so sure. But the Bible, as a whole or in part or any Greek word does not support a created jesus.
JW.org: ”—Compare study note on Php 2:9.”
Thank you. May be next time.

Colossians 1:16 New World Translation renders τα πάντα as “all other things” but why is this is not shown in their Kingdom Interlinear?
The following is an explanation of the NWT rendering of Col, 1:16, as portrayed in jw.org.

all other things: A literal rendering of the Greek text would be "all things". (Compare Kingdom Interlinear.) However, such a rendering could give the impression that Jesus was not created but was the creator himself. And that idea would not agree with the rest of the Bible, including the preceding verse, which calls Jesus "the firstborn of all creation". (Col, 1:15; compare Rev,3:14, where Jesus is called "the beginning of the creation of God.") Also, the Greek word for "all" can in some contexts have the meaning "all other", as for example at Lu, 13:2 ("all other"); Lu, 21:29 ("all the other"); Phi, 2:21 ("all the others"). This agrees with Paul's inspired teaching found at 1 Co, 15:27: "God 'subjected all things under his Christ's feet.' But when he says that 'all things have been subjected,' it is evident that this does not include the One who subjected all things to him." So both the Bible's teachings as a whole and the probable meaning  of the Greek word used here support the rendering "all other things".

Revelation 3:14 NASB

... The Amen, the faithful and true witness, the beginning of the creation of God ...

Here, in Revelation, we have an undoubted reference to Jesus, in regard to his beginning but not then as Jesus, per se, but rather as the Word;  later to be made flesh, in the "guise" of Jesus, the "Prince" of the "King" of creation, as befits the only begotten of God - John 1:14,18
The Word, should really be looked upon as the CONTRACTOR for the ARCHITECT (God). The ARCHITECT creates, formulates a vision and the CONTRACTOR makes that vision a reality. It therefore becomes a matter of opinion as to who, of the two, really is the CREATOR.
Psalm 89:27

... I also shall make him My first-born, the highest of the kings of the earth.

This is a reference to king David, God's "first-born" but with a different connotation. Unlike David, who had dominion over his subjects, to the best of any other king's ability, Jesus, at least initially (as the Word), did not have dominion over his creations .... God did!! So was Jesus the first-born over all creation, or first-born of all creation. Why use the term "first-born", as it pertains to the Word/Jesus, who goes on to create, but doesn't have dominion until after his death - whereupon he becomes the "first-born" from the dead (v. 18) - if he's supposed to be ... the son that has all the rights belonging to the "first-born", because of his preeminent position over all creation (v. 16). There is not to be any "second-born", with the same powerful attributes, to follow him in the act of creation, whereas another all powerful king will follow David.
Jesus' "first-born" status is not to do with his preeminence in creating all (other) things, but rather to do with the fact that he was the first of God's creations, from the "beginning" of time, at least as pertaining John 1:1. Gen 1:1 is another matter, although maybe not ....
Shout out to the Genitive aspect
It has been said (in comment under another poster here), that "... the close proximity of "all creation" (v.15) to "all things created" (v.16), naturally requires the two expressions/clauses, to be synonymous with one another." The even closer proximity, however, is to be found in v.15, alone. IMHO, the close proximity of the "image of the invisible God" and "first-born of all creation", is to highlight Jesus' preeminence/importance and likeness to the Father. The Genitive is nothing to do with "all (other) things created". That's the "Trinitarian" view, in order to try and deflect from the uniqueness/begottenness of the divinity that belongs to the foremost of creation, that is to say "the Son".
NB:-
With the members of this site being predominately "Trinitarian" the urge to downvote will undoubtedly be strong here but if you just have to give in to that emotion, please qualify such action in the comments, out of respect for the "advised" process, as written within the "Code of Conduct", otherwise it is just emotion. I could have downvoted many an answer here but I have not downvoted any. If it later turns out that I do give into such practice here, The poster/s will most certainly be "advised".

I am downvoting this response, for this very reason: The post makes a critical error in attempting to defend the inclusion of the word, “other” in Col. 1:16.  The text is an example of what's called an “ellipsis.”  This is where a clause may lack an element (or perhaps even several) in order to avoid repeating the preceding clause, though the element may be recoverable (or even inferable) from what precedes it.

For example, in the previous sentence when I was defining what I meant as an ellipsis, “An ellipsis is a clause that lacks an element (or perhaps even several),” the parenthetical comment serves as an example of an ellipsis, “An ellipsis is a clause that lacks an element (or perhaps even several [elements]).” The bracketed term “elements,” though originally lacking in the parenthetical clause, is being supplied or inferred from the preceding clause.

Likewise, when Paul states (v. 16), “…because all things in the heavens and on the earth were created by Him,” it is reasonable to infer from the text that it can be taken thusly, “…because all things in the heavens and [all things] on the earth were created by Him.”

@WilliamJordan - At the risk of getting into another extended debate (like with Q: 99833) in the comments section, here, which is not what the section is for, I stand by all that I wrote and indeed referred to in my answer above, which also includes references to Rev, 3:14 (as per Q: 99833). It, of course, is indisputable that all the personal pronouns, He (x 1); Him (x 3), ref. in Col, 3:16 are in reference to Jesus. Whether we believe that Jesus is a separate spiritual personal divinity, from the Almighty, Himself, has long been a matter of debate but not by way of comment here.

@WilliamJordan - My penultimate sentence meant to refer to Col, 1:16, not Col 3:16. I was experiencing the initial pangs of pain, which turned out to be blood clots in the lungs, towards the finishing of that comment.

The reason why The Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures of Jehovah's Witnesses does not have "all other things" in the Greek of Colossians 1:16 is because "other" is not in the Greek text.
It is as simple as that.
Underneath the Greek text is Westcott & Hort's literal English translation, which reads, "because in him it was created the all (things) in the heavens and upon the earth..." etc.
That is why the Jehovah's Witness version of that, in their right-hand-side English translation reads "because by means of him all [other] things were created in the heavens and upon the earth..." etc.
Note the square brackets around 'other'? Square brackets indicate a word added by the writer. That is what the translator wants you to read as his understanding of what the sentence 'really' means. And, in that 1st chapter of Colossians, the translator has added, in square brackets, [other] five times. Yet not once does the Greek text have 'other' in it. That is why the Watchtower Society translator has had to put 'other' in square brackets five times:
The Greek text of Colossians chapter 1 does not have the Greek word for 'other' in it, anywhere.

Summary
The online study edition of the New World Translation acknowledges τὰ πάντα means all things and explains the decision to translate as all other things:

Although God’s firstborn Son, Jesus, is here said to have been involved in the creation of all things, the Scriptures do not call him the Creator. The preceding verse says that he is “the firstborn of all creation,” and at Revelation 3:14, he is called “the beginning of the creation by God.” After his own creation, Jesus, personified as “wisdom” in Proverbs chapter 8, became Jehovah’s “master worker.” (8:1, 22, 30) Jesus’ involvement with creation is described at Proverbs 8:22-31, which says that Jehovah’s master worker “rejoiced over [God’s] habitable earth, and . . . was especially fond of the sons of men [or, “mankind”].” It is in this sense that Colossians 1:16 says: “All other things have been created through him and for him.”

The NWT acknowledges the passage states Jesus has been involved in the creation of all things, but, they claim no other Scripture calls Jesus the Creator. Thus this passage which states He is Creator but uses the term firstborn must be interpreted as saying Jesus was created. As a created being His relationship to the rest of creation must be understood accordingly: in Him all other things were created...all other things through him, and for him, have been created.
I will address the deficiencies in this justification:

Ignoring what Paul wrote to the Corinthians.
Using Proverbs 8, not Genesis 1 to explain the works of creation.
Misunderstanding the term firstborn of all creation.

Of course, the main objection is the premise Paul believed Jesus was created yet failed to explicitly say so. Instead he wrote to the Colossians stating Jesus was the Creator and expected them to use Proverbs to completely change the meaning of what he wrote.
First Corinthians
Where the NWT looks to Revelation to justify their interpretation of firstborn, the most relevant text is Paul's earlier writing about creation.
1 Corinthians 8:6 (NWT)

there is actually to us one God, the Father, from whom all things are and we for him; and there is one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom all things are and we through him.

In describing both the Father and Jesus Paul used τὰ πάντα which is "in the absolute sense of the whole of creation all things, the universe." 1 In so doing Paul states Jesus has the same relationship with respect to the rest creation as the Father.
If Paul believed Jesus was a part of creation, he should not have given Jesus the same relationship with all things as the Father.
All other in Genesis
The obvious place to consider what Paul has to say about creation is Genesis and when we examine Colossians 1:15-17, it is clear Paul uses language and patterns from Genesis.
With respect to πᾶς, the meaning is all. It can mean all collectively or individually. The first use in Genesis illustrates how the difference can lead to all other (or every other).
LXX-Genesis 1:21 (NETS)

And God made the great sea monsters and every πᾶσαν creature among creeping animals, which the waters brought forth according to their kinds, and every πᾶν winged bird according to kind. And God saw that they were good.

The word is used twice; each time the translators understood the meaning as every. However, the first is with life created in the water which is described as two works, sea monsters and every creature among creeping animals which the waters brought forth. As a result, πᾶς can be interpreted relative to one or to both works. With respect to one work it means every; with respect to both, God made the great sea monsters and every other creature...
Life in the water was created in two steps. Therefore, some were created before and from that perspective, the second were every other... Context determines every or every other.
Image of God
The earliest heresies (Marcion and Gnostics) claimed Jesus was a spirit-person. To refute this idea Paul begins by recalling Genesis 1:26.
Colossians 1:15 (NWT)

He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all πάσης creation

LXX Genesis 1:26

And God said, “Let us make humankind according to our image and according to likeness, and let them rule the fish of the sea and the birds of the sky and the cattle and all, πάσης the earth and all, πάντων the creeping things that creep upon the earth.


Genesis 1:26: πάσης τῆς γῆς, πάντων τῶν ἑρπετῶν
Colossians 1:15: πάσης κτίσεως

By starting with image of the unseen God Paul brings to mind the creation of the first man. If Jesus had been created, He too would have been said to be made in the image of God. Of course if Jesus was created before the first man, then, as Jehovah's "master worker" He would be present when Genesis 1:26 was spoken. He would be included in let us make man in our image... His relationship with the rest of creation is as stated in First Corinthians.
Despite believing Jesus was created before all other things, the NWT understands Colossians 1:15 as all. The reason is the firstborn in the phrase firstborn of all creation is included in creation. However, since firstborn would always be included, and since creation includes everything, there is no reason to say "all" creation if firstborn means created first.
Firstborn, πρωτότοκος has another meaning: it pertains to prominence, first, foremost, most important, most prominent." 2 If Paul intends this meaning. then he must add all.
πρωτότοκος κτίσεως        firstborn of creation
πρωτότοκος πάσης κτίσεως  most prominent of all creation

Paul's addition of πάσης effectively demands the reader to understand he is using firstborn to describe Jesus as most prominent of all creation. 3
All With the Article in Genesis
In the Genesis account, πᾶς is used 16 times, 1:21 (2x), 1:25, 1:26 (2x), 1:28 (3x), 1:29 (3X), 1:30 (4x), and 1:31. The first 15 are without the article; the last is with the article.
LXX-Genesis 1:31

And God saw all the things τὰ πάντα that he had made, and see, they were exceedingly good. And it came to be evening and it came to be morning, a sixth day.

πᾶς without the article here would still mean all, God saw πάντα He made means God saw all that He made. Nevertheless, the LXX translator(s) added the superfluous article. Therefore, in Genesis πᾶς without the article can be interpreted either all or all other; adding the article makes all definite. Essentially reading or hearing the article gives emphasis: the all.
Significantly, τὰ πάντα is not used in Proverbs.
All in Colossians 1:16
Paul begins by summarizing verse 15, but he uses the article τὰ πάντα. Then he describes works which continued after the seventh day before repeating the summary using the article.
Colossians 1:16 (YLT)

because in him were the all things τὰ πάντα created, those in the heavens, and those upon the earth, those visible, and those invisible, whether thrones, whether lordships, whether principalities, whether authorities; all things τὰ πάντα through him, and for him, have been created

Paul "brackets" the list using τὰ πάντα before and after. This is necessary since thrones, lordships, principalities, authorities were created after the seventh day. He is (continually) most prominent of all creation, because in Him were created all things (beginning in Genesis and continuing), those in the heavens, and those upon the earth, those visible, and those invisible, whether thrones, whether lordships, whether principalities, whether authorities; all things through Him and for Him have been created.
Colossians 1:17
Colossians 1:17 serves as another summary and recalls Colossians 1:15:
Colossians 1:17 (NWT)

he is before all other things, and by means of him all other things were made to exist
καὶ αὐτός ἐστιν πρὸ πάντων καὶ τὰ πάντα ἐν αὐτῷ συνέστηκεν

Both forms from Genesis are used. The first is without the article πρὸ πάντων and the second is with τὰ πάντα The NWT's rendering of  πρὸ πάντων as before all other things is 100% correct. Since Jesus is before He is not included in πάντων (similar to how aquatic life is described in Genesis 1:21). He is before all other things. He is not  part of creation. He is most prominent.
Verse 15   firstborn, most prominent of all creation
Verse 17a  before all other things 

All other things continues to give Jesus equality with the Father who is also before all other things. Ironically, by correctly understanding πάντων as all other things the NWT correctly understands Paul as saying Jesus, like the Father is not part of creation.
However, both terms in the phrase πρὸ πάντων καὶ τὰ πάντα cannot have exactly the meaning. No one reading Paul's letter would understand πρὸπάντων καὶ τὰ πάντα as the NWT translates. They would recognize 17b means Paul intends τὰ πάντα as all things.

And He is before all other things, and by means of Him all things were made to exist

Paul repeated the theological significance but he used both πάντων and τὰ πάντα in a way which makes his meaning absolutely clear. This restatement must also be considered in the light Paul never said Jesus was created. In other words, Paul not only failed to make the explicit statement Jehovah Witness doctrine holds, he carefully crafted these statements stating Jesus was the creator of all things making certain a reader could not fail to understand that point.
Conclusion
The NWT admits it adds other to what is all things "because the Scriptures do not call Him the Creator." However, that is exactly what Colossians 1:15-17 states. What the NWT really means is in no other Scriptures is He called the Creator. 4
When Paul's letter was read by the Colossians the meaning is clear. To refute the false teachers, Paul states the deity of Christ using language which is consistent with having human nature.

15 who is the image of the invisible God, first-born, most prominent of all creation, 16 because in him were all things created, those in the heavens, and those upon the earth, those visible, and those invisible, whether thrones, whether lordships, whether principalities, whether authorities; all things through him, and for him, have been created, 17 and himself is before all other things, and all things in him were made to exist.

While it is true Scripture interprets Scripture, one must use Scripture which speaks directly to the Scripture in question. Here the NWT's errors are evident. Rather than compare Colossians with First Corinthians which has all things for both the Father and Jesus, the NWT mistakenly looks to Revelation 3:14. 5 Finally, the primary texts for creation are in Genesis 1, not Proverbs 8, and it is clear Paul wrote with Genesis in view.


Fredrick William Danker, A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature, Third Edition, The University Chicago Press, 2000, p. 784.
Ibid., p. 893. Also, firstborn is πρωτότοκος πάσης κτίσεως without the article, not ὁ πρωτότοκος κτίσεως another indication πρωτότοκος means preeminent.
Revelation 3:14 says ἡ ἀρχὴ τῆς κτίσεως τοῦ θεοῦ The term ἀρχὴ also means source, the source of God's creation. He is most prominent because He is the source.
Even misunderstanding Jesus as God's "master worker" makes this claim suspect. As the "master worker" He must be present in us of Genesis 1:26, let us make man in our image... Because He and the Father are one (John 10:30), He is co-worker.
Many would say the NWT's interpretation of Revelation 3:14 is wrong. ἀρχὴ τῆς κτίσεως beginning of the creation... does not use the term firstborn. ἀρχὴ means source which agrees with most prominent in Colossians: source of the creation of God.


Thank you. Is my impression false that in this forum there are more active unitarians and JWs?

@GuidoGaudlitz  In Hermeneutics a Q asking about a text important to JWs will attract lots of JW answers, also some Unitarians who have similar beliefs. It will also attract non-JWs and non-Unitarians who are able to answer it. This forum is open to all who can give considered answers (preferably, politely). But with 'hot potato' texts, comments may escalate into arguments, which is an abuse of the comments function. It is good to develop a discipline of sticking to the Q and answering according to Hermeneutic guide-lines, leaving it at that. The OP may give the green tick to 1 answer, or not.

@GuidoGaudlitz Anne explains how this site works. As to your point my experience is those who deny the deity of the Christ are committed to defending that position and are very knowledgeable about the Bible. I have learned much from interaction with them. If you are diligent and disciplined to the text you will eventually encounter "one way" expressions like Colossians 1:17 which refute wrong positions. One can maintain all other things is correct only by ignoring Colossians 1:17. Because 1:17 is a one way street placed after 1:16.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Starting at Colossians 1:15 I think this verse begins the main theme of the letter; the preeminence or supremacy of Christ. Here the Apostle Paul first described Christ as "the image of the invisible God."
The Bible states in several locations that the essence or substance of God is invisible to human beings (Romans 1:20; 1 Timothy 1:17; Hebrews 11:27). It also states that no man can ever see God, an obvious reference to the Father, but that Christ has made the Father known (John 1:18; and John 14:9).
"Image" expresses two crucial points. First, it suggest "representation, likeness." Hebrews 1:3 reflects the same idea through another Greek term that was translated "exact representation" in the New International Version. "Manifestation" is the second idea reflected in the term "image" (John 1:18; 14:9). Paul also described Christ as "the firstborn of every creature." "Firstborn" (prototokos) DOES NOT IMPLY that Jesus is part of creation, but rather indicates HIS PRIORITY and sovereignty over creation.
Colossians 1:16 reinforces this interpretation by emphasizing that Christ's relationship to creation is not that of being part of it but that of bringing all things into existence. Notice the progression in this passage. First, Paul showed Christ's relationship to deity, and then His relationship to creation.
The words "by him" in this verse would be translated better as "in Him" because they express the fact that He was the agent through which everything was created (John 1:3). the tense of the verb "were created" is aorist in the first instance and perfect tense in the second, referring to the continuous result.
And let's not forget about Colossians 1:17. Here Paul summarizes the previous affirmations of the supremacy of Jesus in creation. Not only did Jesus always exist (John 1:1; 8:58), but He holds creation together. Thus, the Gnostic philosophy that matter is evil and was created by some being other than Christ is completely unscriptural.
And as others have pointed out regarding Revelation 3:14 backs up that Jesus Christ Himself is not a created being. In fact, the word for beginning in the Greek is "arche." We get our English word "architect" from that word and obviously it means that Jesus is the "architect" of creation.
Lastly, Isaiah 44:24, "Thus says the Lord, your Redeemer, and the one who formed you from the womb, I, the Lord, am the creator maker of all things, Stretching out the heavens BY MYSELF, And spreading out the earth ALL ALONE.
I would like to know from the Jehovah's Witnesses perspective as it relates to Colossians 1:16. What are some of these "other things" that Jesus created that was not already created by the Lord God at Isaiah 44:24?

Good points, but the Q asks why the NWT does not have the word 'other' in its  Greek text (KIT) but adds 'other' in their English version The Q flags up an inconsistency with the NWTs rendition of Ephesians 1:10, so if that is explored, then the answer may become apparent. Sticking to the remit of the question is important, as is refusing to be side-tracked by points thrown in by others to get answerers into an off-topic debate.

Comments are for requesting clarification, not for extended arguments of theology.

@Mr. Bond  As the spirit person known among humans as Jesus (in english)  was called "Firstborn" however you may interpret that expression, predating "other" creations and being a partner in these miricles "other" things could include......Angels, Seraphs, Cherubs. Heavenly things we may be unaware of at this time. Spiritual dwelling places for the newly created spirit persons. Physical universe including photons, atoms, quarks. Physical things we are unaware of,  for a few.......  1 Cor 1:27  is interesting.

The answer to this question is not trivial.  There are multiple issues at play here that need to be recognized.
The foremost issue is that the Watchtower front-loads 1:15 to interpret 1:16, rather than allowing 1:16 to naturally explain 1:15.
If you were to ask someone from the Watchtower organization why Jesus is referred to as, “the firstborn of all creation,” they will lead into an elaborate excurses about how Christ is the first thing ever directly made by God, and through that one, everything else was created.  The issue with this, is:
Col. 1:15 is apart of a larger sentence that extends back into 1:13 and continues through 1:17, therefore, Paul’s thought (or “frame of mind”) never shifts.  The subject matter and points of reference stay on point as the sentence progresses.  Paul tells us explicitly why he refers to Christ as, “the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation” in his lead into 1:16.  Paul begins 1:16 with the term, ὅτι (“because”).  It’s usage is to help highlight the reason for appropriating such language to Christ, “the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation, because… .”
The reason given by Paul is not “because” Christ was created before everything else, but rather, “because all things were created in Him… through Him… and for Him.”
This is exactly why the Watchtower employs the word, “other”: In order to downplay the significance of 1:16.
It is sometimes argued that the inclusion of the word, “other” is not required, but can be inferred from the context.  But, again, this is all because they front-load 1:15 with a lot of baggage that really is not necessary.
For example, the Watchtower will use their imagination to interpret 1:15’s πάσης κτίσεως (“all creation”) to include in it a time anterior to Gen. 1:1, pressing back into the periapsis of Proverbs 8.  But as I have explained on other forums, it is more natural to think that Paul’s reference to “all creation” is limited solely to visible/invisible realms to the exclusion of Prov. 8 (cf. 4 Ezra 6:1-38, Jubilees 2:1-10).  Paul is having a totally humanistic experience and is speaking about creation as he perceives it.  It is natural for authors of the period to speak about creation, even “all creation,” without the notion of Proverbs 8 being read back into the phrase, i.e., 4 Ezra 6:1-38, Jubilees 2:1-10.
The close proximity of “all creation” (v. 15) to “all things created” (v. 16), naturally requires the two expressions/clauses to be synonymous with one another. It is difficult to imagine that in the space of just a few short words (even within the very same breath) that “all creation” (v. 15) means anything semantically different from “all things created” (v. 16).  Whereas in 1:15 the phrase “all creation” is left unqualified, Paul goes onto elaborate on what he means by “all creation” by expanding it to the heavens and earth.
Based on the context itself, it seems far more likely that Paul is simply alluding to Gen. 1:1 in his reference to “all creation.”  This is bore out by the fact that Paul alludes to the Genesis mandate multiple times throughout the epistle.  In Col. 1:6, 10 we hear Paul’s call to “bear fruit and multiply,” which alludes to Gen. 1:26-28.  There is also an allusion to Isaiah 11:2 in Col. 1:9.  Tucked away in Paul's allusion to Isaiah 11:2 (cf. Col. 1:9-10) is also a reference to the call to “bear fruit” (cf. Isaiah 11:1).  Since Isaiah 11 was already on the mind of Paul, it would only be natural for him to allude to the call to “bear fruit and multiply,” since the motif is referenced immediately in the Isaian context.  Further still, in Col. 1:12-13, the “kingdom of light” is placed in contrast to the “dominion of darkness,” which are themes from Gen. 1:1-4, but perhaps more specifically with the intentions to invoke Gen. 1:4, where God separates light from darkness.  In Col. 3:10 and 1:15, Paul picks up imago Dei language from Gen. 1:26-28.  And in Col. 1:16, Paul uses a passive verb for the word, “create,” which implies that God was working through Christ in a way that parallels Gen. 1:26-28 (“Let Us make man in our image”).  And finally, in the two contemporary Jewish works cited above (4 Ezra 6:1-38, Jubilees 2:1-10), it was common for authors of the period to project the creation of the angelic hosts back into the Genesis storyline, so it is not out of the ordinary to think Paul is so doing here in 1:16 when he mentions the “rulers,” “powers,” and “authorities.”
Further still, when Paul speaks about creation, he does so routinely with emphasis only on the visible/invisible realms of creation, never to the inclusion of Prov. 8.  You will need to dig far and deep, and even stretch the truth to make Prov. 8 fit.



1 Cor. 15.27: Turning the Table on the Watchtower
Often times representatives from the Watchtower will attempt to justify the inclusion of the term, “other” by jolting to 1 Cor. 15:27.  But 1 Cor. 15:27 in no way helps make their case,

For ‘He has has put all things in subjection under His feet.’ But when
He says, ‘All things are put in subjection,’ it is evident that He is
excepted who put all things in subjection to Him (1 Cor. 15:27)

From 1 Cor. 15:27, the Watchtower wishes to show that while “all things” have been subjected to the Son, it is to the exclusion of the Father — hence, “it is evident that He (the Father) is excepted who put all things in subjection to Him (the Son).” Because God is excluded from those things which have been subjected to the Son, they then argue that τὰ πάντα (“all things”) should be interpreted to mean “all other things.” However, there is a problem: The word “other” need not be assumed to preclude God from “all things,” so long one considers that by “all things” what is being referred to are created things. The actual passage that Paul alludes to here is Ps. 8:6, and in that text τὰ πάντα (“all things”) is a reference to created things, namely (Ps. 8:7–8), “All sheep and oxen, and also the beasts of the field, the birds of the heavens and the fish of the sea, whatever passes through the paths of the seas” things of, “all the earth” (Ps. 8:1, 9). In fact, Col. 1:16 specifically makes this connection when it says, “all things were created in the heavens and on earth” (v. 16), which quite naturally excludes anything outside of the created order without “other” ever being assumed.  Not to mention, the term “created” is a passive verb, which indicates that it is God doing the work (cf. Eph. 3:9, Rev. 4:11) through Christ.  If God is doing the work, then of course it excludes God without needing to include the word, “other.”
The other issue, is: What Paul states in Col. 1:15 is alluding specifically to what he had wrote earlier in 1 Cor. 15, and is speaking about the incarnate, now exalted Christ, and the subjection of “all things under his feet” (Ps. 8:6 LXX).  Christ’s supreme rank is highlighted by the designation, “the firstborn of all creation” (1:15b). This is then followed with the declaration that Christ is the means through which all of creation comes into existence including everything (except God, which is thereby naturally excluded since the passive verb indicates that it is God doing the work through Christ) in the heavenly realms and the earthly realms (1:16a). In addition to being the originating agent of all creation, Christ stands as the ultimate goal of creation (1:16b).
The genitive in 1:15 is best understood in light of the OT allusions coursing through the backdrop.  The discussions surrounding Col. 1:15 are often framed in a way that pit the objective genitive against the partitive genitive, as if the two are mutually exclusive.  My view is that they are not mutually exclusive, but fit together in complimentary paradigms, i.e., Ps. 89:27.  Meaning that this describes the subjection of creation to the incarnate, and now exalted Christ, who conquered death.  In the incarnation Christ entered into, what Paul perceives as, creation and has now been exalted and given dominion over that creation.  Thus, this genitive shades more closely to the objective use (“firstborn over all creation”), but still with incarnation in focus (cf. Col. 1:19, 2:9-10).
Paul is attributing to Christ language (saturated by it’s local/geographic context) that would otherwise be attributed to human kings of the Ancient Near East, by fusing together two lines of thought which intersect with one another: Gen. 1:26-28 (cf. Wsd. 2:12-24), and Ps. 89:19-20, 27 (cf. Sirach 49:16).
Whereas in Sirach 49:16, it is Adam who is exalted above even the greatest and most glorious of men; in Ps. 89:27, it is David who is exalted as the highest of the kings of the earth.  We also hear this theme of being “exalted from amongst the people” in Ps. 89:19-20.  So in some regards, Ps. 89:19-20, 27 communicates something very similar (or akin) to Sirach 49:16, which I believe are concepts and motifs behind what Paul says in Col. 1:15.  There is this fusing together of Adamic thought with Royal Jewish motifs and ideologies.  What Sirach 49:16 communicates about Adam, Col. 1:15 communicates about Christ and in terms nowhere short of Adam.  Hence, when Paul refers to Christ as “the image of the invisible God,” the connection to Gen. 1:26-28 is clear: As the Second Adam, Christ was given dominion over creation, and all things have been subjected to Him, “because,” as Paul adds, “in Him were all things created.”  On that note, it is worth mentioning that 1:15 begins with a linking verb, “is,” which seems to indicate that Paul is not describing a past mode of existence, but is very much focused on Christ’s present state of being in contrast to the things that “were created,” v. 16.
Sirach 49:16 helps provide the “proverbial” bridge between the two data points (Gen. 1:26-28 and Ps. 89:27), of which Paul is alluding to in Col. 1:15.
Of course, this is all for the very purpose of illustrating Christ’s mediation of God’s power, rule, and authority as that enthroned King, God’s image bearer, which further correlates with Paul’s choice use of terms in v. 16 (“thrones,” “powers,” “rulers,” “authorities”).
Alluding back to Gen. 1:26-28, Paul refers to Christ as “the image of the invisible God” (Col. 1:15).  That Gen. 1:26-28 is what’s on Paul’s mind when he writes these words is confirmed from the fact that Paul himself alludes to Gen. 1:26-28 two other times in this very letter: Col. 1:6, 10.  Not to mention, as dictated by it’s local context (i.e., Col. 3:10), Paul’s use of the term “image” has little coherence with the wisdom literature, if at all.  Further, when Paul writes in Col. 2:9 (cf. Col. 1:19) that in Christ “all the fullness of Deity dwells bodily,” this corelates closely with Col. 1:15’s, “He is the image of the invisible God.”  With these factors at play, and Paul’s deliberate use of contrasting terms, “image”/“invisible,” it makes most sense to understand Col. 1:15 as incarnational language with a focus on the exaltation of the risen Lord.  Further, one of the sources that Paul could be alluding to (Wsd. 2:12-24) also points us back to Gen. 1:26-28.
The text in question has a strong presence of dominion and subjection themes.  The use of the “firstborn” epithet is directly influenced by Ps. 89:27 (which also contains themes of dominion and subjection), as is demonstrated in the following way:
Foremost, the language used in Col. 1:18 (“firstborn of the dead”) is in fact an allusion to Rev. 1:5 (or vice-versa).  It is probably more likely that Rev. 1:5 is an allusion to Col. 1:18, but the point is: Rev. 1:5 picks up on language used in Paul’s earlier epistle to the Colossians.  Rev. 1:5 speaks of Christ as, “the faithful witness, the firstborn of the dead, and the ruler (αρχων) of the kings of the earth.”  In Rev. 1:5, John relies on two sources: Col. 1:18, and Ps. 89:27,37.
In the first source (Col. 1:18), Paul uses similar terminology found in Rev. 1:5, “the αρχη, the firstborn from the dead.”  Where Paul uses the term αρχη, John uses the term αρχων.  This may show some correlation between Paul’s αρχη and John’s αρχων.  While Paul never uses αρχων (it is more frequent in John), he frequently uses other related terms to express similar thought. Being that one of John’s underlying sources was Paul’s earlier epistle, it is likely then that the two terms αρχη (Col. 1:18) and αρχων (Rev. 1:5) are thematically related.  Further underlying this is Paul’s use of the singular αρχη (Col. 1:18) in contrast to the plural αρχαι (Col. 1:16).
The second source that influences John’s thought in Rev. 1:5 is Ps. 89:27,37.  Whereas, John speaks of Jesus Christ as, “the faithful witness,” the Psalmist refers to the throne of God’s anointed as, “faithful witness in the sky” (Ps. 89:37).  And in 89:27, where the Psalmist speaks of God’s anointed as “firstborn, the highest of the kings of the earth,” John speaks of Christ as, “the firstborn of the dead, and the ruler of the kings of the earth.”  Ps. 89 lays sway over John’s interpretation of Paul’s words.
Further, as briefly mentioned earlier, Col. 1:15 is apart of a larger sentence that extends back to 1:13, which is an allusion to 2 Sam. 7:14.
Paul has already alluded to Gen. 1:26-28 twice in his lead up to 1:15.  This is all for the purpose of orienting our minds towards that text.  And as the sentence progresses, it is not difficult to see how themes found in 2 Sam. 7 are then carried forward into Paul’s narrative, like: God tabernacling, and the call for David to build God a house.  In addition, in the background text of 2 Sam. 7, there is even mention of David being appointed ruler, and His descendant being given an everlasting kingdom.
Also, in 2 Sam. 7:9, God tells David that, “I will make you a great name, like the names of the great men who are on the earth.”  This has  close correspondance with the passage in Sirach 49:16 that was mentioned earlier.



Testing the Force of τὰ πάντα
But one does not even need to pick up on all these OT allusions (or intertextually related Pauline texts) to see the glaring issue that the Watchtower faces:
Col. 1:16 is an example of what's called an “ellipsis.” This is where a clause may lack an element (or perhaps even several) in order to avoid repeating the preceding clause, though the element may be recoverable (or even inferable) from what precedes it.
For example, in the previous sentence when I was defining what I meant as an ellipsis,

“An ellipsis is a clause that lacks an element (or perhaps even
several)”

The parenthetical comment serves as an example of an ellipsis,

“An ellipsis is a clause that lacks an element (or perhaps even
several [elements])”

The bracketed term “elements,” though originally lacking in the parenthetical clause, is being supplied or inferred from the preceding clause.
Likewise, when Paul states (v. 16), “…because all things in the heavens and on the earth were created by Him,” it is reasonable to infer from the text that it can be taken thusly, “…because all things in the heavens and [all things] on the earth were created by Him.”
The point, is: The Watchtower is busy trying to find excuses for the inclusion of the word, “other,” when the simple fact of the matter, is: Paul intended his reader to assume the very words that they resist the most, “all things.”
If you are going to suggest that Paul intended the reader to mean, “all other things,” then one should be able to test it's force against the backdrop in the way I have so done here.  No one in their right mind would suggest that Paul is trying to communicate that, “[all other things] on the earth were created by Him,” yet, that's what they're forced into if they test this nuance against the elliptical reading.  While an elliptical reading is not necessarily required, it does help test the force that we are told is required from the “context.”  With or without the ellipsis, the text communicates the same idea.
It is really just that simple.
There is almost no way to get around the fact that “all creation” (v. 15) = “all things were created” (v. 16), or that “all creation under heaven” (v. 23) = “all things were created... on earth” (v. 16).  Whereas “all creation” in 1:15 is left unqualified, Paul goes onto (in 1:23) to qualify with the phrase, “all creation under heaven.”  This just shows that whatever Paul meant by “all creation under heaven,” it is synonymous with Paul's statement in v. 16, “all things were created... on earth” (v. 16).  Thus, there really is a strong correspondence between what Paul's unqualified “all creation” (v. 15) and his more descriptive statement, “all things were created in heaven and on earth” (v. 16).  To suggest that “all creation” (v. 15) means anything different than “all things created” (v. 16) is pure dishonesty.

Only just managed to finish the reading of this about an hour ago. A lot to digest again. Having a hard time dealing with all this right now, as believe it or not am in the ER (for the 3rd time this week) but am scheduled to go home again tomorrow, where I have all my resources, so will look at this again tomorrow.

(for the 3rd time in last 8 days) I meant.

I finally found the time, not to mention the health, to go through your truly extensive word-play of Col, 1:15 & 1:16 and quite frankly find it to be in error, to put it bluntly. Even after all that you have said, or tried to imply, for you to end up saying that "all creation" (v. 15) means the same as "all things" (v. 16), is ludicrous. You have completely missed the point that the two are indeed unrelated. For one thing, the first-born of all creation (God's "Only Begotten" in actual fact) did not become the first-born over all creation until after his death. Again a - 1 from me.

You have simply overstated your case.  It requires one to stretch the truth to think "all creation" is semantically different than "all things created," and I discuss why that is throughout this post. The purpose of this post was to demonstrate that Col. 1:15 is not about pre-existence, rather, 1:16 is. That is why I mention 1:19 and 2:9-10, to show their close correlation with 1:15. The allusions to Genesis militate against any such notion of Prov. 8 being read back into "all creation" in the way you front-load the text.

My conclusions are based solely on what Paul says in the immediate context.
If Paul uses certain terms, phrases, or alludes to certain OT texts, then we have to think those texts are what influenced his thought process.  Unless you can demonstrate Paul is not alluding to 2 Sam. 7, Genesis 1, Ps. 89, etc. then you are simply doing one thing: Reading your own theological motives into the text instead of attempting to understand Paul through the OT backdrop that is being supplied in the immediate context.  And the way those OT texts are "intertextually" related is critical to our understanding

The genitive in 1:15 can be understood in a variety of ways. As suggested, it should be understood in light of it's OT backdrop. I already argued that 1:15a alluded to Gen. 1:26-28 where Adam is given dominion OVER creation. I also argued that 1:15b alludes to Ps. 89, where David is appointed firstborn ruler OVER the kings of the earth. Thus, I understand this genitive as an objective genitive ("firstborn OVER all creation") through the lens of Gen. 1 and Ps. 89, but that it also carries a partitive nuance since it speaks about His exalted status as a man, the Second Adam.

The "genitive" aspect of 1:15 speaks to an attributive relationship with God. You say "the close proximity of 'all creation' (v.15) to 'all things created' (v.16) naturally requires the two expressions/clauses to be synonymous with one another". I say the "genitive" aspect is closer than that and is all within v.15. The closer proximity of the 'image of the invisible God' and 'first-born of all creation', is to highlight Jesus' pre eminence/importance and likeness to the Father. Your allusion to Gen, 1:26-28 regarding Adam and Ps. 89 regarding David gets us away from the actual text.

As stated prior, my argument for an allusion to Gen. 1:26-28 is not just 1:15a.
You are failing to deal with the argument.  As I stressed more than three times in the post, the suggestion that 1:15a is an allusion to Gen. 1:26-28 is derived from the fact that Paul alludes to Gen. 1:26-28 three other times in the epistle: Col. 1:6, 1:10, 3:10.  But not only that, but that in two of those instances are in his lead up to 1:15.  That means, if Paul is already alluding to Gen. 1:26-28, then it is also likely the case in 1:15a.

Also, you don't actually believe 1:15 is speaking about an attributive relationship with God.  Because if you did that actually refutes your understanding of the text.  Why?  Because there is also a thing, such as, an attributive genitive.

1:15 communicates precisely what 1:19 and 2:9-10 communicates: That Christ is (and forevermore will be) the fleshly embodiment of all the fullness of God.

Paul's allusion to Gen, 1:26-28, I find somewhat fanciful on your part. Enough already about your understanding of the attributive genitive. We are not that far apart. Christ, while on earth at least, was the "fleshly" embodiment of both his and God's divinity, identical in image (as far as the need may be) and with the "fullness" of God, Himself. But, to make him out to actually be "God in the flesh" is to go a step too far. Was devolved direct from God and consequently essentially God, but is NOT God. We are going to be asked to go to "Chat" shortly but no can do/want to. Sorry!!

I do not find the allusion to Gen. 1:26-28 "fanciful" at all.  It is derived from the text itself without me reading any theogical motivations into it.  You are attempting to dance around those allusions because it does not suit your position.  Your presentation here is a redherring.  I nowhere stated that Christ
was "God in the flesh."  Though I do think that is truthful, I nowhere stated that to be the case.  The text does not say that Christ was the embodiment of "his and God's divinity," but speaks about God's fullness indwelling Christ in "bodily" form, i.e., "image" of the invisible.

To say "we are not that far apart" is an understatement.  We are "far apart." You take 1:15a as a reference to pre-existence, when I think it is very much saturated in "incarnational" language from the epistle itself, i.e., Col. 1:19, and 2:9-10.  This makes the Second Adam motif all the more plausible.
Plus, to suggest Ps. 89:27 is not influential to Paul's thought separates us even further.  You really need to try interacting more with the presentation, and be less "argumentative."  You have yet to provide details from the context that proves my conclusion incorrect.

Oh, believe me, I could indeed interact more with the argument but as I have already said, it is of no necessity for me. You have your conviction and I have mine and I do not believe that the "twain" can meet. Over and out.

Then perhaps instead of wasting the space to type hundreds of words back-and-forth, you could have simply cut to point and demonstrated your opposition so that others could "see" things from your vantage point.  It does not seem your responses are geared at seriously critiquing the position, but are more driven by your theological tendancies and motivations.  That is the real motivation behind your "downvote."

This answer is very much too long. On our site, we look for answers to have some research and citation to explain what a Bible text means and the interpretation process leading to that conclusion. You might read up on how to write a good answer. While we want to be thorough in citing, we need to be brief in presenting the case. Answers and questions here are expected not to be exhaustive or full-length for academic journals. We do brief and concise.

Please edit this and make it shorter, at least half of the current length. The mod team will keep watch.

Many answers have endeavored to paint an unfavorable picture of the accuracy of the NWT in their comments. Some have said the word can "never" be used to include something besides what is stated in the verse itself as apparantly they consider tahe there are no declensions possible for this particular word. This is a false claim. An interprator must use logic to convey the spirit of the thought being conveyed by the inspired writer into another language. The idea conveyed by any one word cannot always be limited to the "general" meaning of the word itself. For instance some have said that to use vs 15 EBR "Who is an image of the unseen God, Firstborn of all creation,— "as a reason to consider Pas in vs 16 to include the expression "other" is unacceptable, however the writer themself is  simply applying their own understanding of the Theology under discussion. As to the possibility of translating the passage to include "other" is clearly explained in the inspired words of the Apostle Paul as he explains the concept further in 1 Cor 15:27 EBR "For—He put all things in subjection under his feet. But whensoever it shall be said—All things are in subjection!—It is evident that it means,—Except him who did put into subjection unto him the All things— "  Evident" ?  Why would this be "evident" if we could NEVER consider Col 1:16 to convey the thought of "other" things in the inspired context considered? (rhetorical questions) It seems evident to many God fearing people who seek to know the true essense of our Heavenly Father that we must allow the entire Bible to speak to our hearts. Thus to imply that the NWT is twisting Col 1:16 by translating Pas to include the word "other"  in order to mislead the reader of NWT is misleading in itself, because how would the person view the expression by Paul at 1 Cor 15:27 that God is excluded from the word Pas found there? We must approach the Scriptures with an open mind and allow God's Spirit to lead us to the "evident" idea conveyed.

Don't you mean 1 Cor, 15:27??

You should read 1 Corinthians 8:6 in the NWT. The exact phrase is translated as all things. Their own commentary states they knowingly add "other" to change the meaning. And they fail to acknowledge Paul could have such that "other" was at least implied.

I can upvote this now.

@Olde English   Thank you for correcting that faix pau.  That verse seems to resolve completely the op's question. Seems evident to me......

@Revalation Lad  Yes, I read the comments as to why the translating committee translated it that way. And at least they explained. But like the intro to the Living Bible, when the exact meaning of a text is unclear, the theology and schooling of the translater will color the translation. No one seems to constantly demonize the translator of that version. I love the paraphrased versions yet realize they must be compared with other sources. With respect to adding "other" in this case, 1 Cor 15:27 gives the thoulogy as to the meaning of Col 1:16. It seems evident this is what is meant.

as to the 2 that downvoted, obviously you simply are prejudice, otherwise you would give reasons for the down vote.

I just added more information to my own answer. Hope you can appreciate.

@ACME. It is obvious that those using delusive reasoning the include Jesus in their concept of a multi person god will try twisted reasoning to convince themselves of their concept of a multi person God. What is clear that their concept of a multi-person God is not the same God as their God Jesus worships. The God of Jesus is not begotten. Jesus' God has no Father. He is the Father. Jesus remained a servant after he was resurrected, and he remained having a God, Acts4 and revelation 3. Jesus God remains God and was never a servant. The God of Jesus is not a multi person God.

The asker asks "According to Jehovah's Witnesses, Jesus is part of the things created. Is this a correct usage of τα πάντα?
It seems that the asker's understanding of Jesus is that Jesus is uncreated, thus he further asserts "This creates the logical dilemma that all things are gathered in Jesus, who is himself part of these things.". On the other hand, if it can be proven that Jesus is part of the things created, then the NWT's ' usage of pas/panta is correct.
Jesus pointed to God as the source of his life. John 6:57. John 3:16, Revelation 3:14. Jesus himself said he was born John 18:37
Let us now examine the Greek word pas/panta.
"All" (is) frequently used for 'some' or 'most' Young's Analytical Concordance of the Bible, 1978
Examples of "all" used in a limited sense in the bible are 1 John 2:20, Christians do not know all things, it just is impossible.
In 1 Corinthians 6:1, Paul said all things are lawful to him. Would rape and murder be lawful to Paul?
In Matthew 28:18, when Jesus said all power is given unto him, did Jesus had power over God? 1 Corinthians 15:27 show that Jesus' use of "all" power was limited not absolute. He has no power over his God.
Notice the phrase "things in heaven and on earth" in Colossians 1:16 and the phrase "whether things on earth or things in heaven" in Colossians 1:20 Paul did not say Jesus made the heaven and the earth.
Jesus Christ who is called first born in Colossians cannot be referring to the Genesis creation as Adam was the first created human being. It thus follows that Jesus is the firstborn a new creation which started from him.
In Colossians 1:16 Paul described the authority structure, not the Genesis creation, that God created in and through Jesus, making him the leader.
Colossians 1:16 could not be used to say that Jesus was the Creator because Jesus was never called the Creator in the bible. In addition, the Greek word (ἐν (en)  denotes instrumentality as bible hub shows.
in
ἐν (en)
Preposition
Strong's 1722: In, on, among. A primary preposition denoting position, and instrumentality, i.e. A relation of rest; 'in, ' at, on, by, etc.
Using Colossians 1:16 to say that Jesus was the Creator in Genesis contradicts verses showing God/ the Father as the only Creator, see Isaiah 44:24 and Deuteronomy 32:6.
An example of "all other" is NLT's and Good News Translation of Ezekiel 31:5 where the Assyrian cedar is excluded from "all", and thus showing the use of all in a limited sense.

It seems that more than one question is posed here.  Let's start with a simple answer to the title question: 'Colossians 1:16 New World Translation renders τα πάντα as “all other things” but why is this is not shown in their Kingdom Interlinear?'
Answer: because their Kingdom Interlinear intends to translate the Greek of the New Testament (Westcott and Hort) word-for-word into English, and the word "other" is not in that original Greek text.  The answer doesn't need to be any more sophisticated than that.
Additionally other questions are asked and consistency of the translation is called into question by citing verses such as Ephesians 1:10 and the rendering chosen for τὰ πάντα there.  Trying to look at this objectively, should translators always render τὰ πάντα the same, regardless of context?  Of course not, that would be absurd.  If that were true, many Bible translations could be flagged as "inconsistent".
Let's take our beloved KJV translation as an example.  In Col. 1:16 it renders τὰ πάντα as "all things".  Yet in Mark 4:11 the very same τὰ πάντα is rendered as "all these things".  Is this correct usage of τὰ πάντα?  The word "these" isn't even in the original text, yet, it would seem that the context certainly allows for it.  There are plenty of other examples that could be pointed to.
However, the question is: can τὰ πάντα be rendered as "all other things"?  Answers to that question are already found here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75762/how-do-jehovah-s-witnesses-explain-the-unique-wording-of-colossians-115-17-in-t
I'd also like to point out that one does not need to go to the Kingdom Interlinear to discover that the word, "other", was not present in the original text of Col. 1:16.  All one has to do is read the footnote in the NWT on this verse to see that the translators fully disclose that they know that the word, "other", was not in the original text.  They also explain their reasons for including it there.

πᾶς means all. In some places it means all other. That is, something is excluded. πάντα is the plural of πᾶς In Colossians πάντα occurs 13 times, 6 with the article τὰ πάντα 7 without. 1) If a passage uses the word with and without the article is it proper to translate as if the writer did not intend a difference? 2) If a writer demonstrates the intentional use of the article is it reasonable to expect a translator to preserve the distinction? BTW your example of Mark 4:11 does not apply. "All these things" includes everything. "All other things" excludes some.

@RevelationLad 1) depends on the context, 2) depends on the context.  If I write the word, "orange" 100 times and 99 times i mean the color and not the fruit...the one time I do mean the fruit, should a reader use the context or the sheer number of other occurrences of the word to determine the meaning?  The Mark 4 example wasn't meant as an apples to apples comparison but I can add another example if you'd like.
